# Android progressbar not showing value

Tags: android

I created [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835278/android-delete-from-list-is-wrong) few hours ago, which I solved my main issue with the help of user @J2K.
Although, I thought the progressbar was doing well..but it's not.

My loop is this:

```
for(int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){

}
```

And he said to change the way I was output the value:

> Change publishProgress((i * 100) / list.size()) to:
>   publishProgress((list.size() - i * 100) / list.size())

The problem is that the value of progressbar doesn't change. It stays always in 0.
So I tried to check the values:

```
Log.e("Value:", String.valueOf((list.size() - i * 100) / list.size()));
```

And I'm always receiving: **Value: -99**, and in the end of the loop:

> 11-07 10:25:43.196: E/Error H:(3187): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

**Edit: Solved.**

Looking at my code of the other topic, the problem is that I was deleting from list the index..so I'll never get the total size of the list.

```
// Where total_list = amount of items in list
int total__ = total_list - i;
publishProgress((total__ * 100) / total_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` is empty..thats why  `list.size()` retuns zero..you are performing divide operation with zero.so it is giving you `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` exception try check whether the list is empty or not..

Comment: .post some more code of your asynchtask by seeing those lines we can't say about it.